# SIGCHLD not being caught

Tags: c, linux, fork, execve, sigchld

I intend the following code to fork and exec "sleep 3" as a child while the parent process sleeps for 10s.  I expect the parent process to receive SIGCHLD after 3s, when the "sleep 3" sompletes.

This does not happen, instead I get:

```
main
parent process
parent sleeping for 10s
child process
child start, command: /bin/sleep, args: 0x7fffc68c8000, env: 0x7fffc68c8020
```

`ps -ef` shows a

```
chris    10578 10577  0 10:35 pts/25   00:00:00 /bin/sleep 3
```

followed by a:

```
chris    10578 10577  0 10:35 pts/25   00:00:00 [sleep] <defunct>
```

for the next seven seconds (at which point the parent process exits).

The issue is that `clean_up_child_process` is never called.

What mistake have I made?

zombietest.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t child_pid;

sig_atomic_t child_exit_status;

void clean_up_child_process (int signal_number) {
    printf("signal received\n");
    /* Clean up the child process. */
    int status;
    wait (&status);
    /* Store its exit status in a global variable. */
    child_exit_status = status;
    printf("child_exit_status %i\n", status);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    printf("main\n");

    int pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        printf("child process\n");
        signal(SIGCHLD, clean_up_child_process);

        char *args[] = { "/bin/sleep", "3", NULL };
        char *env[] = { NULL };
        printf("child start, command: %s, args: %p, env: %p\n", args[0], args, env);
        int ret = execve(args[0], args, env);

        // if we get here, then the execve has failed
        printf("exec of the child process failed %i\n", ret);
    } else if (pid > 0) {
        printf("parent process\n");
        child_pid = pid;
    } else {
        perror("fork failed\n");
    }
    printf("parent sleeping for 10s\n");
    sleep(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling the child to wait for a child process to finish, and then the child process is calling execve which doesn't create a child process, but instead replaces the current program with the one you're execing

You probably want the parent to intercept the child (i.e. have the `signal` call before you execute the `fork` call).

Answer (score 1):

Found it: the call to signal should not be in the `pid == 0` branch, as that process is entirely replaced when execve is called.

Moving the signal call to above the `if` solves the problem.

Comment: Looks like I was writing this as Tom Tanner answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

this line:  `signal(SIGCHLD, clean_up_child_process);` should write in in `(pid>0)` instead of
`(pid == 0)`

See  from [SIGCHLD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_process) :

*The **SIGCHLD** signal is **sent to the parent** of a child process when it exits, is interrupted, or resumes after being interrupted. By default the signal is simply ignored.*

So , the parent received the SIGCHLD , the parent process call the clean_up_child_process .